# Jboss developer studio 11: 'jboss tools wtp server actions' removed from toolbar?

Tags: jboss-tools, jboss-developer-studio

Upgraded to version 11 today. I noticed that the 'jboss tools wtp server actions' in the toolbar is not there anymore.

I used this heavily! Is this a bug or removed functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean these icons? https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-24528

If so then yes, it was an intentional removal.

Instead, please use the Servers view to start/stop/deploy/interact with server instances.

Comment: tnx. are you a a developer from jboss?

Comment: I am, yes. If you'd like to raise this as a bug or feature enhancement, please open a JIRA here: https://issues.jboss.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=10020